# Why do I get a Bad Request with String in MongoDB REST API?

Tags: jquery, mongodb, rest

I am working on a project that has to do with task planning, the only issue I seem to be running into at this point is that when I make a call using MongoLab's REST API.

If there is a `%` in the text it comes back as a bad request, if I change the name in the Document to have no % and then run it again with out the % in the variable it works no problem, but the issue is `resultName` is dynamic and will be for many users and will have many results and someone's result could be "Decrease Bodyweight by 10%".

My code that I use for this is below:

```
resultName = "Reduce everything by 10%";
urlTest = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/myDB/collections/users/?apiKey=myAPIKey&q={"result_name":"' + resultName + '"}';

        $.ajax( 
            { url: urlTest,               
              type: "GET",
              contentType: "application/json",
              async: false
            }
        ).success(function(returnedData) {              
            console.log(returnedData);
       });
```

How can I still allow for `%` sign of other symbols to be used and yet still pull the correct data without a bad request?

Comment: How are you getting on with this, Nicholas? There is an answer waiting for you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider escaping the `%` character first by using the native JavaScript [**`encodeURI()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function and then decode that in your API RESTful GET implementation using the **[`decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)** function.

Some tests to demonstrate this:

```
var resultName = "Reduce everything by 10%";
resultName = encodeURI(resultName);
decodedResultName = decodeURI(resultName);
urlTest = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/myDB/collections/users/?apiKey=myAPIKey&q={"result_name":"' + resultName + '"}';


console.log(resultName);
console.log(decodedResultName);
console.log(urlTest);
```

**Output logs**:

```
Reduce%20everything%20by%2010%25
Reduce everything by 10%
https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/myDB/collections/users/?apiKey=myAPIKey&q={"result_name":"Reduce%20everything%20by%2010%25"}
```

You can thus decode the query object string in your backend using the **[`decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)** function:

```
db.test.insert([
    { "result_name": "Decrease Bodyweight by 10%" },
    { "result_name": "Reduce everything by 10%" }
])

var q = {"result_name":"Reduce%20everything%20by%2010%25"}; 
q.result_name = decodeURI(q.result_name);
db.test.find(q);
```

gives:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5549f951180e849972939049"),
    "result_name" : "Reduce everything by 10%"
}
```

Comment: The encodeURI and decodeURI worked for me. 

The example code with the db.test.insert does not apply to me, being that I am currently doing AJAX calls to the mongodb.

Comment: @NicholasDarley Thanks for the feedback, glad that worked out for you.